# CQL filter not displaying in leaflet.js

Tags: leaflet, wms, cql-filter

I have a CQL filter that only displays a certain number of points, however when I try to apply the CQL to my existing leaflet map through the options for a layer nothing displays. No errors are thrown in the console.

Any ideas?

```
http://SERVER.com/geoserver/Workspace/wms?VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&SERVICE=WMS&LAYERS=Workspace:Layer&STYLES=Point&BBOX=3026,2004,657587,1244444&SRS=EPSG:27700&WIDTH=570&HEIGHT=1035&FORMAT=image/png&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&CQL_FILTER=NAME='Leeds'
```

Below is what I have tried

```
 var FilterWMSlayer= L.tileLayer.wms("http://Server.com/geoserver/Workspace/wms", 
    {
        layers: 'Workspace:Layer',
        format: 'image/png',
        transparent: true,
        CQL_FILTER:NAME='Leeds'

    });



   var FilterWMSlayer= L.tileLayer.wms("http://Server.com/geoserver/Workspace/wms", 
    {
        layers: 'Workspace:Layer',
        format: 'image/png'&CQL_FILTER=NAME='Leeds',
        transparent: true
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 var FilterWMSlayer= L.tileLayer.wms("http://Server.com/geoserver/Workspace/wms", 
    {
        layers: 'Workspace:Layer',
        format: 'image/png',
        transparent: true,
        CQL_FILTER:'NAME=Leeds'

    });
```

### EDIT

In case you want to query more params:

```
CQL_FILTER:'param=value&param1=value1&...'
```

### EDIT 2

I've updated your fiddle. 
http://jsfiddle.net/ZkC5M/274/

The problem is the quotes.

```
cql_filter : "RMIGroup = 'Almond Catchment ARMI'"
```

Use double quotes `"` for the entire string you pass to cql_filter and single quotes for the value of the property.

Comment: No luck however I noticed `CQL_FILTER=NAME=%27Almond%20Catchment%27`   instead of `CQL_FILTER=NAME='Almond Catchment'`    when I submit the URL which returns the working map

Comment: For some reason it displays properly without the CQL filter when using leaflet however when I add it the SRS gets set to `srs:"EPSG:3857"` but still a blank box

Comment: That's because the browser is scaping some character entities to format the URL. I think my approach is correct. Note that you have to pass a String to cql_filter. You're doing cql_filter : name='Almond Catchment' . The correct way is cql_filter : 'name=Almond Catchment'.

Comment: `cql_filter : 'NAME=Almond Catchment'`  No luck, but the SRS does change from 27700 to 3857 as soon as I add the CQL filter. I may have to pull a JS fiddle together

Comment: Yes! It would help to answer your question. =)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZkC5M/254/  You'll see that i've placed the working URL in addition to the CQL within the options. When not commented out nothing is displayed.

Comment: See my edited answer. Hope it works correctly!

Answer (score 0):

Simply Set CQL Filter with onclick Function:

```js
    var map = L.map('mapid').setView([39.998769, -75.1448316], 10);
    var wmsLayer = new L.TileLayer.WMS('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/IA/wms', {
        layers: 'IA:final_table',
        format: 'image/png',
        transparent: true,
        version: '1.3.0',
        crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326,
        maxZoom: 20,
        // set deafult cql_filter
        // cql_filter : "STATE_CODE = 'AL'" 
    }).addTo(map);
```

Onclick Function for CQL FIlter

```js
    function filterUpdate(){
        // access global variable with wmsLayer and set the Prams with setParams Function
        wmsLayer.setParams({CQL_FILTER:"STATE_CODE = 'AL' AND update = FALSE"});
    }
```

use it with HTML button or some other way with javascript

```html
    <button onclick="filterUpdate()">CQL Filter Button</button>
```